# Show $X/A$ is $T_1$, but not Hausdorff

Tags: general-topology

I have to do this exercise where we let $A=\{\frac{1}{n}\mid  n\in\mathbb{N}\}\subset \mathbb{R}$. We let $\mathcal{B}$ consist of all open intervals of $\mathbb{R}$ together with the sets of the form $(a,b)\setminus(A\cap(a,b))$, $a,b\in\mathbb{R}, a<b$. We let X be the topological space obtained from equipping $\mathbb{R}$ with $\mathcal{T}$, where $\mathcal{T}$ is the topology generated by $\mathcal{B}$. We need to show that $X/A$ is $T_1$, but not Hausdorff. To show that $X/A$ is $T_1$ I am thinking I have to show that the one-point sets $\{x: x\in X/A\}$ are closed in $X/A$. To show that $\{x: x\in X/A\}$ are closed in $X/A$, I am thinking that I have to show that $X/A\backslash\{x: x\in X/A\}$ is open, but I am a little confused about how to do so. Furthermore I am little confused about how to show that $X/A$ is not Hausdorff, I am thinking I have to find an counterexample, but I have a hard time thinking of one, or maybe if I can show that $X/A$ is Hausdorff $\Rightarrow$ A is closed. And I know that A is not closed hence $X/A$ will not be Hausdorff, but I don't know how to show $X/A$ is Hausdorff $\Rightarrow$ A is closed.

Comment: Is $X=\mathbb R$?

Comment: X is the topological space obtained from equipping $\mathbb{R}$ with $\mathcal{T}$, where $\mathcal{T}$ is the topology generated by $\mathcal{B}$.

Comment: Assuming $X/A$ is the quotient space I believe you can show that there are no disjoint open sets containing $0$ and $1$, respectively. This is because any open neighborhood around $0$ contains a point of $A$ which is equivalent to $1$ in the quotient space.

Comment: So we start by saying that we let U be an open neighborhood of $0\in X/A$ and we let V be an open neighborhood for $1\in X/A$, and the we want to show that $U\cap V\neq \emptyset$. The way we show that $U\cap V\neq \emptyset$ is by taking $\frac{1}{n}\in A$ which is in U as well (How can we be sure that such a point exists?), and then we have that $\frac{1}{n},1\in A$, so we'll have that $\frac{1}{n} \sim 1$, hence $\frac{1}{n}\in U$? hence $U\cap V\neq \emptyset$. Is that how the argument would go?

Comment: You are right about $U$. Since we allow points of $A$ to be missing we can find a neighborhood around $0$ not containing points of $A$ which is the singleton $1$. In fact, we need that to prove the space is $T_1$. But, since $1$ is equivalent to $A$ in the quotient space, it is closer to $0$ then any $\epsilon\gt 0$. Therefore, you must argue that although $0$ may not be in $V$, any neighborhood of $1$ contains points in a given neighborhood of $0$.

Comment: I am not quite sure what you are saying I am right about?

Comment: You were asking how we know there is a point of $A$ in $U$.

Comment: And how can we be sure of that?

Comment: And how can I argue that although $0$ may not be in , any neighborhood of 1 contains points in a given neighborhood of $0$?

Comment: Isnt’t this provins that X/A is not Hausdorff?

Answer (score 1):

Open sets in the quotient space correspond to those sets whose inverse under the quotient map are open in the original space. Given a one point set $\{x\}\subset X/A$ Its complement in $X$ is $(\{y:y\lt x\}\cup\{y: y\gt x\})$ minus any points of $A$. But intervals missing points of $A$ are open in $X$ so we have the union of two open sets which is open. Therefore, complements of one point sets are open in $X/A$ and so given $x,y\in X/A$, $x\in\{y\}^c$ and $y\in\{x\}^c$ so $X/A$ is $T_1$

To show that $X/A$ is not Hausdorff, let $0\in U$ and $1\in V$ where $U$ and $V$ are open in $X/A$. Consider any interval around $1$ in $V$. Its inverse under the quotient map contains all points of $A$ which get arbitrarily close to $0$. Consider the inverse of an interval around $0$. It doesn't necessarily contain points of $A$ but, given $\frac{1}{n}$ and $\frac{1}{n+1}$ in $A$ there will be a point in between those values that is in the interval around $0$.

Therefore, $U\cap V\ne\emptyset$ and $X/A$ is not Hausdorff.

Answer (score 0):

In $X$ we cannot separate $0$ and $A$ (which is closed) by disjoint open sets, and it follows that in $X{/}A$ we cannot separate $q(0)$ from $q[A]$. Being $T_1$ is obvious as all classes are closed.